# Is it possible to use a TensorFlow model created with 2.0 with a later version?

Tags: tensorflow

New to TensorFlow here - and subject says it all. Before I go down a rabbit hole of incompatible versions: Is it possible to use a TensorFlow model created with 2.0 with a later version (2.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use model created in 2.0 in 2.2 and later 2.x versions without any error, in case you face any please create an issue for us to help you out.